# How do I tell sublime text which virtualenv I want to use

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, sublimetext3, virtual-environment

Hi I have created a virtualenv `test_env`.

It is located `C:\Users\firstname.lastname\test_env`

Inside this `test_env` folder there are some sub folders with the packages I have installed in my virtualenv.

I want to use this virtualenv to run python files in sublime text 3 although I am having trouble.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1) Installing the sublime package virtualenv in my sublime text I have passed in the path of the virtualenv `C:\Users\firstname.lastname\test_env` and activated the environment, this didn't work so I tried the same but giving `C:\Users\firstname.lastname\test_env\Scripts\activate` and `C:\Users\firstname.lastname\test_env\Scripts\python` neither of which worked.

2) Creating a build system in sublime

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Users\\firstname.lastname\\test_env\\Scripts\\python", "-u","$file"],
    "selector": "source.python",
    "file_regex": "^\\s*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)"
}
```

and then building with this.

This also didn't work and my code runs with an error.

To test that I'm using the virtualenv I just installed a package to the virtualenv that python doesn't have by default and then I am running that in sublime text.

I know there are several posts about similar issues but I have tried them and I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

Your build system should more likely be the following :-

```json
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Users\\firstname.lastname\\test_env\\Scripts\\python.exe", "-u","$file"],
    "selector": "source.python",
    "file_regex": "^\\s*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)"
}
```

You need to specify the python executable needed to run the file & not the python folder (which anyways doesn't exist in the `Scripts` directory).

Comment: I just tried this and it does not work unfortunately :(

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct python executable in the `cmd` from the intended virtual env ?. I tried by creating a virtualenv on my end on a windows machine & it worked correctly.

Comment: Yes I believe I did, I pointed it to the python executable that sits within the virtualenv I created.

Comment: Any errors in the console ? Incorrect build systems don't give errors. If there was something wrong with it, it would have either showed an error dialog or build system not detected or something along those lines. Have you checked to see if the above build system is indeed the one that's being used ?